# How do I install MongoDB 2.6 for OS X?

Tags: mongodb, macos

I've inherited a legacy project at work that requires MongoDB 2.6 as a dependency. My first instinct was to check brew for it.

```
$ brew search mongodb
==> Formulae

mongodb                    mongodb@3.2                mongodb@3.6
mongodb@3.0                mongodb@3.4                percona-server-mongodb

==> Casks
homebrew/cask-versions/mongodb-compass-beta
homebrew/cask/mongodb
homebrew/cask/mongodb-compass
homebrew/cask/mongodb-compass-community
homebrew/cask/mongodb-compass-readonly
homebrew/cask/orelord-mongodb
```

Yup... mongodb is there, but only version 3.0 and up, which does not help me. I then checked the official mongodb site and found that it's the same story there: only 3.0 and up are provided.

Searching through google, all that I'm finding are recommendations to install using homebrew or through the official website, both of which are apparently no longer options. I'm not sure what other services provide 2.6 that are trustworthy (which is important to me and my employer). Have I overlooked something?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.org/dl/osx

Comment: @DaveNewton Wow, where'd you find that link? Really helpful though! If you put that in an Answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I searched Google which lead to a question on superuser. Since this isn't a programming question, I won't answer it.

Comment: Please upgrade your project to a newer version of MongoDB as soon as you have the opportunity. MongoDB v2.6 has reached its end of life as of October 2016.